# MySQL IF/WHEN/ELSE/OR

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I'm trying to retrieve a single row from a database, unless it doesn't exist, in which case I want it to retrieve the second row. I've got the code written out, but for some reason it's retrieving both rows. If the first row is not found, it retrieves the second row. So regardless it always retrieves the second row.

```
SELECT *
FROM `members`
WHERE
`id` = 49
or `id` = 0
```

I've tried many variations (when/then/else, etc) on different databases with different columns, and it always retrieves both rows.

How can I retrieve just the one row that I need? And also, can anyone explain to me why it does this?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp check this page

Comment: @Brake Karasoy:The trouble with that method is that it's not versatile. I want to retrieve id 49 first, but sometimes the second one might have an id higher than 49

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which is the row that you want first?  `id = 49`?
You could try using mysql's `ORDER BY` combined with a `LIMIT` to get your desired results. For example if you wanted to get id 49 first you could do:

`SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = 49 OR id = 0 ORDER BY FIELD(id, 49, 0) LIMIT 1`

This will order the results by the field `id` but limit the results to only a single row.  So if there exists no row with `id = 49` it'll still get the first row in your list which would be `id = 0`

Comment: The trouble with that method is that it's not versatile. I want to retrieve id 49 first, but sometimes the second one might have an id higher than 49

Comment: the value of the id doesn't matter in this case, if you use `ORDER BY FIELD` it will simply order your results by how you list them in the following comma separated list.  To add to my answer if you wanted to get id 0 first all you would have to do to change this is use `ORDER BY FIELD(id, 0, 49)` instead

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you, that's definitely helpful. By the way, why does this function work this way? This seems impractical.

Comment: Are you referring to the `ORDER BY FIELD()` functionality or the `LIMIT` or a combination of them?

Comment: Neither. The IF and WHEN/THEN/ELSE. Why do they return both if the first condition is met? Is this normal?

Comment: I think perhaps you misunderstand what the IF, etc control functions are useful for.  They don't filter the rows returned but the data within the rows.   In your case you wanted to return the first existing row in a list.  Think of it like modifying the already returned columns instead of filtering them.

Comment: I see! Thank you. I understand the purpose of that function now.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to use `union all` with some logic for verification:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM members m
WHERE id = 49
UNION ALL
SELECT m.*
FORM members m
WHERE id = 0 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM member m2 WHERE m2.id = 49);
```

Under some circumstances, this could be marginally faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can order by statements:

```
ORDER BY (id = 49) DESC
```

The `DESC` because `(id = 49)` is `1` for the row you want first.

If you only want 1, `LIMIT 1`. If you want more, you can chain these into custom sorting:

```
ORDER BY (id = 14) DESC, (id = 43) DESC, (id = 49) DESC LIMIT 3
```

etc.

Very easy to remember.